# How can I calculate costs for Apache beam pipelines running on Google Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I wanted to get an estimate on my Apache Beam Pipeline costs running on Google Cloud DataFlow, I am currently running an Apache Beam code that scales pipeline automatically using a for loop and am storing the data in Beam itself for 12 hours around before aggregating and processing the data in pipeline. Any Ideas on how can I estimate the cost would be appreciated and optimization ways to minimize this costing as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For cost calculation of your Dataflow job, you can get the resource metrics of  in the detail page of your job showing the DAG, steps, at the right side :

**Resource metrics**

- Current vCPUs 2
- Current memory 8 GB
- Current HDD PD 25 GB
- Current SSD PD 0 B
- Total DCU usage 0.14

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-monitoring-intf

Then there is a link allowing to calculate the cost of your job based on your resource metrics (workers, vCPUs, memory, Disk usage...) :

https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator

The price calculator is proposed for classic `Dataflow` job and `Dataflow prime`.
`Dataflow prime` is a new optimized execution engine allowing vertical autoscaling in a worker and also other features : https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/enable-dataflow-prime

You can also check this link : https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pricing

Example with `Dataflow prime`, in this example the job average duration per month is 7.5 hours :

[image]

In this case, the result is :

[image]

Comment: This make things very clear for me!!
You're great bro

Comment: Is there something I need to do to see this for dataflow? I cannot seems to find dataflow under the calculator. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78239539/how-can-i-get-a-sense-of-the-cost-of-my-dataflow-prime-job

Answer (score 1):

Pricing for Dataflow are based on resource usage, which are billed per second usage(Varies from location). For pricing details please visit this [link](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pricing.).  If you want to know how to check your resources you can check at Dataflow resource monitoring [interface.](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-monitoring-intf)

Also for sample use cases and quotations you can contact Google's [sales](https://cloud.google.com/contact?direct=true)