# how can i get a sense of the cost of my dataflow prime job?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

The top answer to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74050648/how-can-i-calculate-costs-for-apache-beam-pipelines-running-on-google-dataflow) mentioned a [calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator?hl=en), but I cannot find dataflow in it.

[image]